# Change default directory index apache2

Tags: apache, apache2

I'd like to change the page that is shown when a directory doesn't have an index.php/html page.

I made a php page that I'd like to use, but I don't know how to set it as a default. I don't want to copy the file into every single directory.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure this is the httpd.conf under the DirectoryListings setting
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

```
DirectoryIndex yourpage.php index.html index.htm index.php welcome.html
```

Comment: Where do I put the file?

Comment: This file is located in the /etc directory either in /etc/httpd or /etc/apache2

Comment: I know where the config is. I meant where do I put my new index page file.